# widget size in pixels

Tags: android, android-widget

How to get widget size in pixels?

I am using Note 3 smartphone, I took screenshot and calculated manually, should be `1020px x 316px` (+-5px), 4x1widget (resizable).

[image]

I tried the code bellow, but I get wrong results:
`minW_dp=324dp, maxW_dp=439dp, minH_dp=69dp, maxH_dp=88dp.`
`minW=782px, maxW=1060px, minH=167px, maxH=213px.`

How to get real size of widget in pixels?

```
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)
{
    int minW_dp = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int maxW_dp = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH);
    int minH_dp = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
    int maxH_dp = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT);
    int minW = dpToPx(minW_dp, context);
    int maxW = dpToPx(maxW_dp, context);
    int minH = dpToPx(minH_dp, context);
    int maxH = dpToPx(maxH_dp, context);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(minW, maxH, Config.ARGB_8888);
}

public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context context)
{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dpToPx` calculation is wrong. You need to change it from:

```
int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
```

to

```
int px = Math.round(dp * displayMetrics.density);
```

If you read the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) it gets obvious why your calculation couldn't work. *(Note: DisplayMetrics.xdpi seems to be messed up on some devices as well, see [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0))*
 Following what **displayMetrics.xdpi** represents:

> The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X dimension.

But you don't wanna get the pixels per inch of your screen. You wanna get the scale-factor, that's where **displayMetrics.density** comes into play:

> The logical density of the display. This is a **scaling factor for the
>   Density Independent Pixel unit**, where **one DIP** is **one pixel on** an
>   approximately **160 dpi screen** (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen),
>   providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi
>   screen this density **value will be 1**; **on** a **120 dpi screen** it would be
>   **.75**; etc.

**Note:** The Note 3 is a *xxhdpi* device and thus has a scale-factor of 3.0 (480dpi).

#### Edit

An other way to calculate the dp->px:

```
(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, maxH_dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, changed dpToPx calculation, but I still dont get ~1020x316. I get: minW=972px, maxW=1317px, minH=207px maxH=264px. Why is that?

Comment: Mhh, strange. Are you sure that you measured the px correctly manually? I mean it's a pretty simple calculation which you can do on your own as well. (dp * 3.0)

Comment: Picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyRV.jpg . It is about 1020x313, hard to tell exact because edges are blur.

Comment: Just checkd this and you're measurement seems fine. I just digged a little deeper and it seems that the density value isn't the actual density of the display, but the density used by the OS. Please see my edit for an other way to calculate the correct px, maybe this will work.

Comment: I get exactly the same values as in first comment using your dp->px.